# Problem with redirect with PageReference in iframe

Tags: commandbutton, pagereference, redirect, iframe

I open a visualforce page in an iframe witch contain two commandButton.

The buttons call functions on the class.

At the end of my functions, i made a redirection with PageReference but the redirection is made inside the iframe...

How can i do the redirection in the same window, a new window, or just refresh the page ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a `<apex:outputPanel` on the action of a `<apex:commandButton` as below. And inside the `<apex:outputPanel` you can refresh the parent page with the redirect URL with this script `window.top.location.href = '{!redirectUrl}';`. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Opp_Ext" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Do Stuff" action="{!doStuffAndRedirect}" rerender="redirectPanel" />
        <apex:outputPanel id="redirectPanel" >
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!shouldRedirect}">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.top.location.href = '{!redirectUrl}';
                </script>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class Opp_Ext {
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public String redirectUrl {public get; private set;}
    public Boolean shouldRedirect {public get; private set;}

    public Opp_Ext(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.stdController = stdController;
        shouldRedirect = false;
    }

    public PageReference doStuffAndRedirect() {
        shouldRedirect = true;
        redirectUrl = stdController.view().getUrl();
        return null;
    }
}
```